# Mapping user email to ADO user/descriptor

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

With a git commit, I have access to the author and committer's email and I wish to map that to a user in Azure DevOps. I've done some due diligence in searching this up but I cannot find anything concrete. I've basically reached the same state as the following post: [Getting user/users details based on user name/alias as parameter in azure devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58110334/getting-user-users-details-based-on-user-name-alias-as-parameter-in-azure-devops)

I can see on the Graph API page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) that this is not yet officially supported. The problem is as follows: is there a way to get back a user descriptor from simply an email?

> Searching by UPN or Display Name
>
> COMING SOON!
>
> Often, identities are represented simply as display names such as
>   Jamal Hartnett or UPNs such as *jamal@contoso.com*. These are not
>   unique at any scope. Search is an resource that will take a text
>   string and run a search across an account or project to find all
>   potential matches. The more distinct the input, the better chance the
>   resource will return a single result. The search resource will accept
>   display names, aliases, UPNs, and email style strings such as Jamal
>   Hartnett jamal@contoso.com.

If the commit author email matches the pushed by email, I can use the [IdentityRef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#identityref) object from that. But for other cases where this does not apply, I'm at a loss on how to map to a descriptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is as follows: is there a way to get back a user descriptor from simply an email?

As far as I know, the official Rest API  doesn't support obtaining descriptors by email.

But based on my test, it seems that this requirement is available.

You could get this Rest API in `Browser Console tab` when you filter the user in `Organization Settings -> Users`.

[image]

Rest API sample:

```
https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/Organization name/_apis/UserEntitlements?%24filter=name%20eq%20%27user@domain.com%27&%24&api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

Then you could get the user descriptor in the API result.

[image: Descriptor]

In addition ， the official Rest API supports to [list all user Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/graph/users/list?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1). You could get the user descriptor in the result too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think given how many users are in our organization, enumerating everything and parsing the results does not seem like a plausible option. This does seem to answer the problem posed though, despite its limitations.

Comment: Yes, this is only a temporary workaround. You can temporarily use this API and wait for the official rest api to launch.